# if statement not working properly for 3 numbers

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

first of all i don't have any intention in making this code big, I know there are ways to cut it short but i wanted to know why this specific code is not working.

Taking input of five numbers from the user

```
a=int(input("Enter the value of a:"))
b=int(input("Enter the value of b:"))
c=int(input("Enter the value of c:"))
d=int(input("Enter the value of d:"))
e=int(input("Enter the value of e:"))
if a>b:
    if a>c:
        if a>d:
            if a>e:
                print(a,"is the largest")
elif b>a:
   if b>c:
        if b>d:
          if b>e:
                print(b,"is the largest")
elif c>a:
     if c>b:
         if c>d:
              if c>e:
                   print(c,"is the largest")
elif d>a:
     if d>b:
        if d>c:
          if d>e:
                print(d,"is the largest")
else:
    print(e,"is the largest")
```

The if branching is only working if a and b have the largest values and not working for the rest

Comment: you can do the same like `print(sorted([int(input()) for i in range(5)])[-1], 'is the largest')` why do u do it like this?

Comment: ...or with just `max()`.

Comment: You need to rethink your logic. If `a` is greater than `b` for example, but `a` is not the greatest, only the first branch of the `if/elif` chain will be executed, and nothing will happen (because the inner `if`s don't all pass). The most minimal fix for what you have is simply to make the `elif`'s into their own `if`s - but as others are saying, this isn't really the best way to determine the largest of a set of numbers.

Comment: You can use the `and` operator here without all the nested if conditions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's indents are wrong. You should add your conditions in 1 line. Let's assume b>a and c>b . First elif condition is returns true b>a . But second indent of elif condition b>c is false. So whole if condition returns nothing cause second elif returned true and indent is returned false. So other elif and else scopes is not worked.

**Why your code is not worked?**

[image]

**Your code should be like this:**

```
a=int(input("Enter the value of a:"))
b=int(input("Enter the value of b:"))
c=int(input("Enter the value of c:"))
d=int(input("Enter the value of d:"))
e=int(input("Enter the value of e:"))
if a>b and a>c and a>d and a>e:
    print(a,"is the largest")
elif b>a and b>c and b>d and b>e:
    print(b,"is the largest")
elif c>a and c>b and c>d and c>e:
    print(c,"is the largest")
elif d>a and d>b and d>c and d>e:
    print(d,"is the largest")
else:
    print(e,"is the largest")
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to max of these you should use if you wanna do it easy way

```
a = int(input("Enter the value of a:"))
b = int(input("Enter the value of b:"))
c = int(input("Enter the value of c:"))
d = int(input("Enter the value of d:"))
e = int(input("Enter the value of e:"))   
print(max(a,b,c,d,e), "is the largest on these nums" )
```

Comment: This question doesn't ask how to find the max number, it asks for debug help with the specific implementation in the question...

Answer (score -2):

```
print(max([a, b, c, d, e]), 'is the largest')
```

"max" is a Python built-in function that can return the biggest item. You can pass in multiple args or an iterable (i.e. a list of numbers).

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: This question doesn't ask how to find the max number, it asks for debug help with the specific implementation in the question...